# Python - Find Object with Matching Value

Tags: python-3.x

I retrieved JSON from an API that looks like this:

```
"entries": [
    {
        "cuid": "1234",
        "name": "23423423",
        "id": "5432",
    },
    {
        "cuid": "12234",
        "name": "123124",
        "id": "5432",
    },
```

I am trying to loop through a separate list of names and retrieve the corresponding ID from the matching object.

I used **json.loads** to store the JSON in `users_dict` where I'm trying to retrieve the value from.

Essentially, say I had name = "23423423" , How could I find the object with that name within users_dict and retrieve the id of "5432" from it.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MaxFarsikov I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution using a CSV as a list:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader: 
    user = (' '.join(row))
    for i , val  in enumerate(users_dict):
        if (val["name"] == user):
            deletion_list.append(val["id"])
```